# WebDav Pdf Saving error

Tags: pdf, webdav

I have set up a webdav folder that I can access thorugh chrome and edit files and save them back to the server, for example, I can open a word doc, edit it and save it back.

When I come to open a pdf, it wont save back to the server and downloads a copy of the pdf instead of the original.

Is there a way of enabling this to edit a pdf?

My end goal is to be able to open a pdf, add comments/highlights and save it back to the server, through my browser.

Thank you

Edit:

I have set this up through Apache 2.4, no plug ins through chrome, I have mapped a network drive to the server folder where I can open and edit files. Except PDFs, I would like to add comments to a off but when I open one the option is greyed out and when I try and save it after opening it tries to save to my desktop.

Comment: You might want to provide a bit more information. Are you using a chrome plugin? What webdav server are you using?

Comment: Im using windows xp with apache, I have just set up a simple http-dav file to connect to a folder, which I point IE at to access the files. It comes up with a list of files; I can open, edit and save the doc, xls, text files, but when I open a pdf it opens it up with a (1) as it has copied it to a temp folder on the HDD and then opens the copy, if I then click save it tried to save it to my local documents instead of the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i've got your use case right, but if i've understood you correctly you have a link in a web page to a PDF which you're viewing in chrome. You click on that link and the PDF downloads to a temp file from which it is opened. If you edit and save those changes are simply saved to the temp file on your local PC. Is that correct?

If so, then this is simply normal behaviour for links in web pages. There is absolutely nothing in the HTML standard which suggests links should be opened by an editor with knowledge of the source location.

What you really want is for the link to launch an editor program which retrieves the remote document in edit mode (probably locking the remote resource) and then have edits saved back to the server. For this to happen there generally needs to be some special interaction in the browser. In Internet Explorer this is provided by the sharepoint dll and special script code. I think there's a plugin for Chrome which does the same thing, although differently.

I havent used the Chrome plugin, but i think this might help - https://code.google.com/p/npapi-msdocs/